# How to async an api response inside a conditional statement?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function which has an API call inside an 'if' condition.When I execute that function, before completing the API response, the program moves to below code lines.That breaks the functional flow since some below codes are running before API response comes Below is my code.

```
 change(event: any) {

    let selectedUnitIds = event.source.value;
    let newUnitIds = this.getNewUnitIds(selectedUnitIds);

    if (newUnitIds.length !== 0) {
      this.commonServerService.getOrgUnitById(newUnitIds).subscribe(orgUnits => {
        orgUnits.forEach(unit =>
          this.unitMap.set(unit.id, unit)
        );
      });
    }


    //get selected ids' orgunits
    let selectedOrgUnits = this.getSelectedUnits(selectedUnitIds);

    // get tribes of those orgunits
    let need = this.getNeededTribes(selectedOrgUnits);
  }
```

The problem here is the if condition. If this API is called unconditionally, inside the subscribe method, everything is working asynchronously. Please guide me through this.

later added:- common-server.service.ts

```
 getOrgUnitById(id: string[]): Observable<Array<OrgUnit>>
  {
    return this.orgUnitService.findOrgUnitByIds(id);
  }
```

Comment: can you also post the getOrgUnitById() function from commonServerService?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put your code in the response block, it will execute only after completion of API call then, like below -

```
change(event: any) {

let selectedUnitIds = event.source.value;
let newUnitIds = this.getNewUnitIds(selectedUnitIds);

if (!newUnitIds.length) {
  this.commonServerService.getOrgUnitById(newUnitIds).subscribe(orgUnits => {
    orgUnits.forEach(unit =>
      this.unitMap.set(unit.id, unit)
    );
     this.someAnotherMethod();
  });
} else {
     this.someAnotherMethod();
  }
}

someAnotherMethod() {
  let selectedOrgUnits = this.getSelectedUnits(selectedUnitIds);
  let need = this.getNeededTribes(selectedOrgUnits);
}
```

Comment: that works only if newUnitIds.length is not zero. It doesn't tackle the part newUnitIds.length == 0

Comment: I tried to avoid code duplication because it is not an allowed practice in my workplace. :)

Comment: @TharushiGeethma good, you can call some global method then. Though no doubt chance of code optimization is always there. :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use 'await' before "this.commonServerService.getOrgUnitById"
You will need to declare "change" function as an async

```
async change(event: any) {

  let selectedUnitIds = event.source.value;
  let newUnitIds = this.getNewUnitIds(selectedUnitIds);

  if (newUnitIds.length !== 0) {
    const orgUnits = await this.commonServerService.getOrgUnitById(newUnitIds);
    orgUnits.forEach(unit =>
      this.unitMap.set(unit.id, unit)
    );
  }

  //get selected ids' orgunits
  let selectedOrgUnits = this.getSelectedUnits(selectedUnitIds);

  // get tribes of those orgunits
  let need = this.getNeededTribes(selectedOrgUnits);
}

async getOrgUnitById(id: string[]): Promise<Observable<OrgUnit[]>>
{
  return await this.orgUnitService.findOrgUnitByIds(id).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it is said that 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression

Comment: You will need to do it in getOrgUnitById too. See updated answer

Comment: really is it possible to await for observable?

Comment: Probably yes. I suggest to return Promise<Observable<Array<OrgUnit>>>. See updated answer :)

Comment: Now it says :: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Observable<OrgUnit[]>>'.ts(2339)
unit-search.component.ts(38, 65): Did you forget to use 'await'?

Comment: probably not because even if you return promise it's only usable inside subscribe method not the return type. also mixing promise and observable like this is not a good practice.

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha can you provide an answer for the original question?

Comment: Could you provide a stackblitz or something ?
I'm not sure about my last suggestion (toPromise())

Comment: @TharushiGeethma i prefer Pardeep Jain's answer .

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha it's code duplication :) I tried that method but sonar is rejecting it :(

Comment: What does it says?

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` and `await` as below code.

To use below code every method call `change()` method should be `async`.

```
 async change(event: any) {

    let selectedUnitIds = event.source.value;
    let newUnitIds = this.getNewUnitIds(selectedUnitIds);

    if (newUnitIds.length !== 0) {
      try{
        await this.getOrgUnitById(newUnitIds);
      }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    //get selected ids' orgunits
    let selectedOrgUnits = this.getSelectedUnits(selectedUnitIds);

    // get tribes of those orgunits
    let need = this.getNeededTribes(selectedOrgUnits);
  }


  getOrgUnitById(newUnitIds){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.commonServerService.getOrgUnitById(newUnitIds).subscribe(orgUnits => {
        orgUnits.forEach(unit =>
          this.unitMap.set(unit.id, unit)
        );
        resolve(orgUnits)
      },error=>{
        reject(error)
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: It's the same solution than mine. You just use new Promise and kicked off return type on getOrgUnitById

Comment: you don't need to create a promise like this you can use `toPromise()`